# How permissions in Hyperledger composer are implemented in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have well understood that in order to maintain security and privacy over data in the hyperledger fabric you need to use different channels. Only peers who have joined a specific channel are synced with the data of the corresponding blockchain. How can we exploit these concepts in Hyperledger composer? How is the permissions file related to the concept of privacy? Is the data saved by the peers, even if they don't have access to it? In this case, is a malicious attack enough to retrieve data or information about them?